# Setup dynamic search in CakePHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, search

I am using the [search](https://github.com/CakeDC/search) plugin for CakePHP.

I try to dynamically setup the `$filterArgs` array that is used for filtering the input from the user. The reason why I want to do this is because my customers can create customer specific input fields. I want to make them filterable and searchable.

**Customer.php:**

```
public function beforeFind($queryData) {
    $this->filterArgs['garantie'] = array(
        'type' => 'subquery',
        'method' => 'findCustomerCustomFieldsByText',
        'field' => array('Customer.id'),
        'encode' => true    
    );
}
```

Debugging `$filterArgs` shows that the entry was made:

```
array(
    'garantie' => array(
        'type' => 'subquery',
        'method' => 'findCustomerCustomFieldsByText',
        'field' => array(
            (int) 0 => 'Customer.id'
        ),
        'encode' => true
    )
)
```

Unfortunately the method `findCustomerCustomFieldsByText()` is not called.

It looks like `beforeFind()` might not be the correct method to call. What callback-method should I use so I can use dynamic creation of `$filterArgs`?

Edit:
My question is not identical to the linked question because it is about the callback methods that prevent the filter from working.

Comment: beforeFind() might indeed be too late, unless you load the behavior at runtime in the action itself, $this->Behaviors->load() etc.

Comment: I am not sure what you exactly mean. Can you be more precise in an answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically create the $filterArgs array in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176167/dynamically-create-the-filterargs-array-in-cakephp)